# Button layout on Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone help me with these buttons? I want them to look like the four in the picture but I don't know how.

[image: Example]

I'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is you set the background to the Activity, and create `Buttons`, hope you are okay with that part ,

And then you can use the `android:alpha=""` property in each button to make it more transparent or opaque, it can have a value from `0` to `1.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TableLayout in your XML file to make them all align. Use the weight property to give them size and choose an opaque background color.I used the following code in a Relative Layout and it came pretty close:

```
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:text="Button" //Store this in your strings resource folder
            android:background="#a6000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"//Store this in your dimens resource folder/>
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#a6000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#a6000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"/>
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#a6000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the layout as you want above. Please refer the below XML.
Hope it helps!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5"
android:alpha="0.5"
android:background="@drawable/backround"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
android:alpha="0.5"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:layout_height="0dp">
<!--Put your any content here-->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:alpha="0.5"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp">
<LinearLayout

android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp">
<Button
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp">
<Button
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```